# Renaming log4j log level

Tags: logging, log4j

Is it possible to have log4j print WARNING instead of WARN without a need to write a custom code?

**Edit:**
I do not want to change tens of thousands lines of code with log.warn(...) in it to be changed. I want log4j to print different log level text for log.warn. Is this possible nor no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy, create a new logging level in log4j following this tutorial (copy & paste):

http://jaikiran.wordpress.com/2006/07/12/create-your-own-logging-level-in-log4j/

I did it successfully ;-)

Comment: Thanks, does a custom log level fit into the log level hierarchy? I would like this log level sit right between INFO and ERROR, any way to do that?

Comment: Yes it does, you can define its place.

Comment: Great that is good. Is there any way to do this without changing the existing lines of code (tens and thousands spanning across multiple apps), for example log.warn(...)? I have updated the question.